# Changing the color of minDate in react-calender when any other date is selected

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am using a react-calender npm. It allows us to use custom calendar in react.
The link below is the live demo of what I am doing:

https://codesandbox.io/live/4ac4910b380

```
 <Calendar
    onChange={changedate}
    value={date}
    minDate={new Date()}
  />
```

This is my code for using the calendar. There is a minDate prop which allows us to select the minimum date beyond this date user cannot select a date. I am using current time(new Date()) as the minDate.  When I am trying to select any date other than the minDate, the minDate's color is becoming yellow
[image]

I could not think of any way to change this color to white. I tried using tileClassName prop but it is also changing the color of the tiles which are disabled. I do not want to do that.

Is there any way to change the color of minDate to any other color without changing the color of any other tile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add this class in your css file..

```
.react-calendar__tile--now {
  background: #purple; //or another color you want
}
```